# Почему bat файл ищет для запуска файл, находящийся в той же папке, в совсем другой директории?

Tags: node.js, windows, cmd, bat, автозагрузка

Я пытаюсь с помощью установленной в `Windows` `node.js` запустить тест из библиотеки тестирования `Cypress` при включении компьютера. Создал `.bat` файл в автозагрузке:
[image: скриншот]

В том `.bat`файле команда:

```
node testCall.js
```

Командная строка по непонятной мне причине ищет файл по пути `С:\Windows\system32`:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему поиск происходит в `С:\Windows\system32`, а не в том каталоге, из которого запускается `.bat` файл?

Comment: .BAT ищет исполняемый файл в текущем каталоге. Если текущий - не тот, где файл (а по умолчанию для CMD текущий каталог - это каталог профиля пользователя, впрочем, зависит от версии ОС), то и не запустится. Потому первой строкой батника нужно выполнить CD /D в нужный каталог. Или указать полный путь к файлу в параметре.

Answer (score 0):

В комментарии уже написали, в чём проблема, но я напишу более развёрнуто.

Когда вы "в ручную" открываете `cmd`, она открывается из "каталога по умолчанию". А это `C:\Windows\system32`. При запуске `bat`-файла происходит то же самое, только команду набираете не вы, а батник.

Командная строка ищет файлы  в текущем каталоге, если вы не указали полный путь к файлу. А раз текущий каталог - `C:\Windows\system32`, то `cmd` ищет там ваш файл и выдаёт ошибку: "не могу найти файл".

**Как исправить проблему:**

Вам нужно просто перейти в тот каталог, в котором лежит ваш файл.
В вашем `.bat` файле пропишите:

```
cd полный_путь_к_папке
```

Если папка лежит не на диске `C:`, то всё чуть-чуть сложнее.
Например, у вас есть папка `d:\programs`. Вот как к ней перейти:

```
cd /D d:\programs
```

`/D` - это буква диска.

Вот [здесь](https://comp-security.net/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA/) можно почитать про переходы в папки. Или, например, [здесь](http://paratapok.ru/os/4318_kak-smenit-disk-v-cmd/) .